# Cчитать всё содержимое файла в строку

Tags: python

Скажите, пожалуйста, как в Python считать всё содержимое файла в строку?

Comment: f = open("foo", "r")
s = f.read()
f.close()

Ну и в s будет содержимое файла.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('ваш_файл.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
```

Теперь в переменной `s` будет раскодированное содержимое файла в виде одной строки.

Answer (score 0):

Считываете файл как обычно, только убираете переносы строк:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    response=file.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
```

Comment: Тогда уж и \r тоже надо вырезать...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов добавил

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вообще-то после текстового чтения '\r' не должно остаться.

Comment: Не думаю, что в вопросе просили удалять переводы строк.