# как импортировать txt файл в беседу вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Как импортировать содержимое txt файл в беседу.
Надо что бы,на любое текст,бот отправлял все строки из файла txt.

Вот образец кода,что я собрал,но ни чего у меня не получилось,пишу в беседе привет,и ответа нет.

```
import vk_api, json
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from config import main_token

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = main_token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

#file = open("myfile.txt", encoding="utf-8" )
#print( file.read() )

from importlib import resources
#with resources.open_text("books", "data.txt")
#file = open('data.txt', 'w')            # open output file object: creates
#file.close( )                           # closed on gc and exit too
#with resources.open_text("books", "data.txt")
#f = open('data.txt','r')
#file.readlines()

#handle = open("data.txt", "r")
#data = handle.read()
#print(data)
#handle.close()

#f = open('data.txt', 'r')

#f = open('data.txt')
#for line in f:line
#'\n'
#'The end.\n'
#'\n'


#file = open('data.txt', 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8')
#body = file.read()
#file.close()

#input(body)

#file = open('data.txt', 'r')             # open input
```

решетки означают,что я проверил их все,и спрятал их от питона.

А вот,этот код рабочий,но без импорта из txt.

```
import vk_api, json
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from config import main_token

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = main_token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            if event.from_chat:

                msg = event.text.lower()
                id = event.chat_id

                if msg in ['пока', 'привет']:
                    sender(id, f'@{event.user_id}, Приветствую тебя!')
```

Comment: Поясните-ка ещё раз, зачем эта куча закомментированных строк с различными попытками открытия файла? Какой именно код Вы запускаете и он не работает так, как нужно?

Comment: Если не знает ответ,так и не пишите.

Comment: Спасибо, но я сам разберусь, что мне писать, а что нет. Смысл Вашего кода абсолютно не понятен и никто не сможет узнать ответ, пока Вы не поясните, что Вы там хотели сделать. Хотите получить ответ – отвечайте на уточняющие вопросы. Привыкайте, это SO, чтобы Вам что-то объяснили, нужно сначала объяснить всем, что Вы вообще хотите.

Comment: Мне нужно,что бы,если пользователь напишет в беседе,любое сообщение,и сразу появлялось  сообщение из файла txt,от имени сообщества.

Comment: Это я уже понял из вопроса. Повторю свой вопрос: *Поясните-ка ещё раз, зачем эта куча закомментированных строк с различными попытками открытия файла? Какой именно код Вы запускаете и он не работает так, как нужно?*

Comment: Нижний код рабочий,и вот его нужно подкорректировать,а закомментированных строк много,для того,что-бы я потом мог проверить,вводил я определенный код или нет.Да и показать людям,что я,что то пытался делать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728526/344284), по сути, дан ответ на Ваш вопрос, т.к. единственное, что у Вас не получилось, – считать текст из файла.

Теперь, если перейти к Вашему коду, реализовать нужное можно как-то так:

```python
import vk_api, json
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from config import main_token

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = main_token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            if event.from_chat:

                msg = event.text.lower()
                id = event.chat_id

                if msg != '':
                    with open('<Название файла>.<расширение>') as text_file:
                        text = text_file.read()
                        sender(id, text)
```